# Multiple Date Comparison Queries

Tags: excel, vba, format

Is there an efficient way of identifying which date is the maximum date across 12 columns of data which all have different dates? Naturally the easiest approach is MAX(RANGE A: RANGE L) and then pull that value down to get the rest of the rows. However, this isn't what I want.

What I want to do is to create a function where I can compare the dates across rows and if it is the max - highlight that value. This is because each column is responsible for a specific part of a process and I want to identify where is the largest delay.

My initial thoughts were defining 2 variables and having them each hold one value temporarily and performing a check to see if var 1 > var 2. If it is, then move to the next one (FOR EACH) loop - otherwise max value is reached. Highlight that value.

Would anyone be able to assist me?

Comment: It sounds as if you could do it fairly easily with a custom formula in Conditional Formatting, but it's tagged as VBA so I guess you want to do it that way.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks! I'm aware of the Custom Formula method but I haven't given it a crack as I've been trying to build up more of my VBA experiences :)

Comment: How I had done it (without VBA) was just use a simple conditional format highlighting the max value (top 1) without any custom formulas. With Custom Formulas - It seems I can't input MAX(Range X: Range Z) because it will just highlight all the values. This should be resolved shortly - i'm sure. However I am very keen for the VBA solution as well :)

Comment: I've solved my issue with the custom formula - =B2=MAX($B2:$J2) and it works well now :) VBA assistance would still be appreciated however